Google app engine: call from another domain not working
calling an app engine (jetty @WebServlet) from another domain gives an error. In the logs I see the 'preflight' successful result, but the servlet code is not reached (a printout as the first line does not appear in the logs). Making the call from a browser works. no authorization involved. tried CORS in app.yaml, no success. not a custom domain

from browser works and same call from a localhost app does not work
preflight call shows up in the logs for both browser and localhost call. the first line log printout of the webservlet code appears in browser call and not for localhost call
tried CORS handler in app.yaml, did not help
no firewalls restrictions defined in app engine project
not a custom domain

Angular call to code:
public getNewCatalogObject(id: string): Observable<any> {
            //const cataloginfoshttp = environment.apiURL + '/' + CatalogInfo + '?catalogname=' + id;
            const cataloginfoshttp = environment.apiURL+ '/' + CatalogInfo;
            const params = new HttpParams().set('catalogname',id);
            const headerdata = new HttpHeaders()
                .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET')
                .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type');
            alert("OntologycatalogService without params: " + cataloginfoshttp);
            alert("OntologycatalogService params: " + params.toString());
                    return this.httpClient.get(cataloginfoshttp,{ 'params': params, 'headers': headerdata })

Webservlet code:
@WebServlet(name = "CatalogInformationServlet", urlPatterns = { "/cataloginfo" })

public class CatalogInformationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CatalogInformationServlet.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        logger.info("CatalogInformationServlet");

preflight log from google app
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog",
    "appId": "e~blurock-database",
    "versionId": "2",
    "requestId": "660fa92c00ff0ba0838e379e6f0001657e626c75726f636b2d6461746162617365000132000100",
    "ip": "212.247.157.170",
    "startTime": "2024-04-05T07:33:00.777537Z",
    "endTime": "2024-04-05T07:33:00.786930Z",
    "latency": "0.009393s",
    "megaCycles": "188",
    "method": "OPTIONS",
    "resource": "/cataloginfo?catalogname=dataset:ThermodynamicContributions",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
    "status": 200,
    "responseSize": "152",
    "referrer": "http://localhost:4200/",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0",
    "urlMapEntry": "auto",
    "host": "blurock-database.ew.r.appspot.com",
    "instanceIndex": -1,
    "finished": true,
    "instanceId": "00a22404dc913688c9e38d2629cbacea000cd13536d1f9f80d60c2b1277a5df1d41f6afb14979e602dd05cb917c3b4e549604721c4b8ed59aefae040a2b7f9e71d67",
    "appEngineRelease": "1.9.71",
    "traceId": "c2a4b7970a7899c6b6b8ddc84334ef73",
    "first": true,
    "spanId": "10870129278550620427"
  },
  "insertId": "660fa92c000c0273cf4bdb2d",
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 200
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "gae_app",
    "labels": {
      "zone": "eu6",
      "version_id": "2",
      "module_id": "default",
      "project_id": "blurock-database"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-04-05T07:33:00.777537Z",
  "labels": {
    "clone_id": "00a22404dc913688c9e38d2629cbacea000cd13536d1f9f80d60c2b1277a5df1d41f6afb14979e602dd05cb917c3b4e549604721c4b8ed59aefae040a2b7f9e71d67"
  },
  "logName": "projects/blurock-database/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log",
  "operation": {
    "id": "660fa92c00ff0ba0838e379e6f0001657e626c75726f636b2d6461746162617365000132000100",
    "producer": "appengine.googleapis.com/request_id",
    "first": true,
    "last": true
  },
  "trace": "projects/blurock-database/traces/c2a4b7970a7899c6b6b8ddc84334ef73",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-04-05T07:33:00.903523715Z",
  "spanId": "10870129278550620427"
}

Unsuccessful attempt to add CORS To app.yaml handler:
- url: /cataloginfo
  login: optional
  secure: optional
  static_dir: /__static__
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type, Authorization"
    Access-Control-Max-Age: "3600"

A further unsucess is adding a filter:
{
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    // Initialization code, if needed
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    // Allow cross-origin requests from any origin
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    // Allow the OPTIONS method
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");

    // Allow specific headers
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

    // Continue the chain
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // Cleanup code, if needed
}

}

You're implementing CORS (manually, which is error-prone) within a handler that you've bound to a GET route, but CORS-preflight requests use OPTIONS as their method. Therefore, preflight requests are not handled properly and CORS preflight fails.

So in Angular (typescript) how do I NOT handle CORS manually? But it is a CORS problem??  And if it is a CORS problem, is it the client or the server that is creating problems... my app.yaml attempt was trying to repair something at the server end... I was hoping that I could but something in the @WebServlet definition, but to no avail -- bottom line, I am still not sure where the problem lies.

I am beginning to suspect that this problem lies in the IAP of the google app engine project (the server is.a google app engine project written in java). Could this be so?

Your assumption was right. IAP has CORS disabled by default. Enabling the same will fix the issue. It is already discussed in this document:

Each App Engine service has a different subdomain which would make the JavaScript requests between the services cross-origin requests. When a browser detects a CORS request, it first sends an OPTIONS (preflight) request to the endpoint before sending the actual request, the actual request is only sent if the response to the preflight request contains the access-control-allow-origin header with the value containing the origin domain or the wildcard *. More information about CORS can be found here. IAP has CORS disabled by default. Enabling the same will fix the issue.

You can enable HTTP OPTIONS (CORS preflight) request on IAP by following this public documentation.

I believe this is one step closer... I clicked the Enable HTTP Options to enable. However, I still get the same behavior... What I am not sure, in this respect, is the interaction with the OAUTH 2 settings. To get the OK on the IAP, a credential was created with a redirect domain set to https://iap.googleapis.com/v1/oauth/clientIds/315685320181-......

Also I set the IAP slider to off, supposedily meaning IAP off: , i.e. no restrictions..... I am also not sure if my problem now is in the client call --- I went back to default with the app.yaml, i.e. no extra handler information dealing with CORS.

@EdwardBlurock, Can you share the error from the browser?

Not sure what you mean... Bút from the browser, there is no error.. even with a curl call there is no error. It is only when I try to access from an angular application (from localhost and from a google app engine server). Both the browser and angular get to the OPTIONS (for me this means that the HttpClient call is correct, at least it finds the server) call but only the browser/curl arrive at the first line of the RESTful code.

Can you try Access-Control-Allow-Origin:\* without double quotes?

Tried this (app.yaml) ... no luck..  Actually no sure that the specification in the app.yaml spec is where the problem lies. I think that the spec in the header of the HttpClient is enough....

just to say, I have also tried adding a CorsFIlter...

public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
public void init. ...
public void doFilter ...
throws IOException, ServletException {
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

The problem was caused by the response of the OPTIONS call did not have the proper CORS header. If the OPTIONS preflight call was not made (for example, just having 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in the header), then the response had to have, for example, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' so the browser would not reject the call.
To get (in a global way, in JAVA) all responses to have the proper CORS parameters, a filter can be added:
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // Initialization code, if needed
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        // Allow cross-origin requests from any origin
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        // Allow the OPTIONS method
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");

        // Allow specific headers
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
                "content-type,authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods");

        // Continue the chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Cleanup code, if needed
    }

Note the
Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods

also have to be listed in the headers.
In the web.xml file to enable the filter:
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>info.esblurock.background.services.service.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

The angular (typescript) header was set up:
 const headerdata = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('content-type', 'application/json')
    .set('authorization', ' AccessToken ' + token)
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

Using the advice of 'Roopa M', the OPTIONS call has to be enabled. In the google cloud console this can be done, but I also added the code to the app.yaml file:
access_settings:
  cors_settings:
    allow_http_options: "true"

In my researches, the following link was very useful.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
Also using the 'Browser Console' in firefox to see the errors the browser was giving was very useful.
